# how to retrieve data from a grid inside modalpopupextender in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am having a modalpopupextender which has a gridview. I can load data's and populate the grid but can't retrieve the selected row values to the particular text box in the parent aspx file.

Comment: Is the GridView in part of a separate user control file or is it coded into the aspx page itself?